# Python: NameError: name "string" is not defined, not via input()

Tags: python-3.x

The function below checks to see if the first 9 digits of string (n) equate to the 10th character (an integer from 1-9 or X for 10).

```
def isISBN(n):
    checkSum = 0
    for i in range(9):
         checkSum = checkSum + (eval(n[i])*(i+1))

    if checkSum%11 == eval(n[9]) or (checkSum%11 == 10 and n[9] == 'X'): return True
    else: return False
```

When I run the function for `n='020103803X'` I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

I've searched for this problem and found that most people's issues were with `input()` or `raw_input()`, but as I am not using `input()`, I'm confused as to why I can't test if a character is a specific string. This is my first post as Python beginner, please tell if I'm breaking rules or what extra info I should include.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? You need to add another tag.

Comment: Why on earth is a python beginner using `eval`?

Comment: What were you expecting `eval` to do with the X? `eval('X')` isn't `'X'`, just like `eval('3')` isn't `'3'`.

Comment: If you want to get the integer value of a number that's stored as a string, use `int()`, not `eval()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your use of `eval`: `eval('X')` is the same as doing `X` (without the quotes). python sees that as a variable reference, and you have no variable named `X`.

There is no reason to use eval here. What are you hoping to accomplish? Perhaps you should be checking to see if the character is a digit?

```
if checkSum%11 == n[9].isdigit() or (checkSum%11 == 10 and n[9] == 'X'): return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a response from

```
eval('X')
```

This is illegal, as you have no symbol 'X' defined.

If you switch the order of your **if** check, you can pass legal ISBNs.  However, it still fails on invalid codes with an **X** at the end.

```
def isISBN(n):
    checkSum = 0
    for i in range(9):
        checkSum = checkSum + (eval(n[i])*(i+1))

    if (checkSum%11 == 10 and n[9] == 'X') or \
            checkSum%11 == eval(n[9]):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Note also that you can short-cut that **return** logic by simply returning the expression value:

```
return (checkSum%11 == 10 and n[9] == 'X') or \
        checkSum%11 == eval(n[9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I don't know how I didn't think of using int(). The reason I used eval() was because the past few programs I wrote required something like

```
x = eval(input("Input your equation: "))
```

Anyways the function works now.

```
def isISBN(n):
    checkSum = 0
    for i in range(9):
        checkSum = checkSum + (int(n[i])*(i+1))

    if n[9] == 'X':
        if checkSum%11 == 10: return True
        else: return False
    elif checkSum%11 == int(n[9]): return True
    else: return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Eval is not the proper usage, nor is the way you use it correct. For example, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Uses) which shows the use. You probably want to use a try: except: pair.

```
try:
     int(n[i]
except:
     print "this character is not a digit"
```

> A call to eval is sometimes used by inexperienced programmers for all
>   sorts of things. In most cases, there are alternatives which are more
>   flexible and do not require the speed penalty of parsing code.
>
> For instance, eval is sometimes used for a simple mail merge facility,
>   as in this PHP example:
>
> $name = 'John Doe';
>   $greeting = 'Hello';
>   $template = '"$greeting,
>   $name! How can I help you today?"';
>   print eval("return $template;");
>
> Although this works, it can cause some security problems (see §
>   Security risks), and will be much slower than other possible
>   solutions. A faster and more secure solution would be changing the
>   last line to echo $template; and removing the single quotes from the
>   previous line, or using printf.
>
> eval is also sometimes used in applications needing to evaluate math
>   expressions, such as spreadsheets. This is much easier than writing an
>   expression parser, but finding or writing one would often be a wiser
>   choice. Besides the fixable security risks, using the language's
>   evaluation features would most likely be slower, and wouldn't be as
>   customizable.
>
> Perhaps the best use of eval is in bootstrapping a new language (as
>   with Lisp), and in tutoring programs for languages[clarification
>   needed] which allow users to run their own programs in a controlled
>   environment.
>
> For the purpose of expression evaluation, the major advantage of eval
>   over expression parsers is that, in most programming environments
>   where eval is supported, the expression may be arbitrarily complex,
>   and may include calls to functions written by the user that could not
>   have possibly been known in advance by the parser's creator. This
>   capability allows you to effectively augment the eval() engine with a
>   library of functions that you can enhance as needed, without having to
>   continually maintain an expression parser. If, however, you do not
>   need this ultimate level of flexibility, expression parsers are far
>   more efficient and lightweight.